# wpf - reference error with office assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

So I've been trying to export my wpf Grid to an excel sheet. But when I tend to import the *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel* assembly I get an error at the following:

```
public partial class SKT : Page;
```

It says this:

> 'Page' is an ambiguous reference between 'Controls.Page' and 'Excel.Page'

Can someone help me out with this, how do I need to do this?

P.S.

Please add some code as an example

Many thanks!

Comment: ayy it is, couldn't find that thread, but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Page" is no longer unique as a Type, so you have to fully specify the name of the Page class you want to inherit from (`Control.Page` or `Excel.Page`).

Sounds as if you want to inherit from `Control.Page`:

```
public partial class SKT : Control.Page;
```